# Как HTML разметку вставить в JS?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Всем привет, помогите вставить html разметку в JS.

Написал код на одном домене онлайн-помощника.

HTML

```
 <!--<div id="open_chat_dev2Studio"><div class="shc sh_btn_char_trans">О</div><div class="shc sh_btn_char_trans">н</div><div class="shc sh_btn_char_trans">л</div><div class="shc sh_btn_char_trans">а</div><div class="shc sh_btn_char_trans">й</div><div class="shc sh_btn_char_trans">н</div><div class="shc sh_btn_char_trans"><br/> </div><div class="shc sh_btn_char_trans">п</div><div class="shc sh_btn_char_trans">о</div><div class="shc sh_btn_char_trans">м</div><div class="shc sh_btn_char_trans">о</div><div class="shc sh_btn_char_trans">щ</div><div class="shc sh_btn_char_trans">ь</div></div><div id="chats_room_dev2Studio" style="display:none;"><div id="panel_work_groups"><div class="text9834">ОНЛАЙН ПОМОЩНИК </div> <div class="dfh_wel"></div></div><div id="loading"></div><form method="POST" id="logins" action='javascript:void(null);' onsubmit='call()'><input type="hidden" name="id" value="24324"><textarea name="mess" id="mess" placeholder="Опишите Ваш проект или задайте нам вопрос."></textarea><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></form><div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
```

И JS

```
$('#open_chat_dev2Studio').click(function(){
$('#chats_room_dev2Studio').slideToggle();
$('#open_chat_dev2Studio').slideToggle();
return false;
});

$('.dfh_wel').click(function(){
$('#chats_room_dev2Studio').slideToggle();
$('#open_chat_dev2Studio').slideToggle();
return false;
});

function call(){
  var msg=$('#logins').serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'//url/server/send.php',
    data:msg,
    success:function(data){
       $("#mess").val("");
        gsd()
      $('#loading').append(data);

    },error:function(xhr,str){
      }
    })
 }

function update() {
 var last_id=$(".im_ch:last").attr("id");

    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'//url.com/server/uploade.php',
    data:{'last_id':last_id},
    success:function(data){
    $('#loading').append(data);
     gsd()
    },error:function(xhr,str){
}})}
setInterval("update()", 1000);

function gsd(){

        $("#loading").scrollTop(10000000000);
      }
```

Так вот, код полностью робочий, вот только проблема: мне нужно подключить этот код с одного домена на другой, типа фрейма, но фрейм не катит. (

Можно как-то написать этот код на чистом JS и подключить таким типом:

```
<script src="min.js"></script>
```

Или как-то подгрузить его как фрейм, только JS технологией?

Перегуглил все, ничего не нашел. (
Что можно сделать, как подключить код к другому домену?

Пробовал так подгружать:

```
$("#div1").load("demo_test.txt #p1");
```

Не работает так.

Comment: Если у вас есть `<iframe>` и вы хотите изменять его содержимое при помощи JS родительской страницы - то это невозможно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Загружаете с сервера на другом домене js скрипт, который содердит ваш html код(экранированный, конечно же) и js код внутри функции, которую надо вызвать после подгрузки скрипта.
другой-домен.рф/script.js содержит следующий код:

```
funcation runMe(){
var htmlCode ="тут ваш экранированный html";
$('#место-куда-вставлять-html').html(htmlCode);
//тут вставляете ваш js код
$('#open_chat_dev2Studio').click(function(){
$('#chats_room_dev2Studio').slideToggle();
$('#open_chat_dev2Studio').slideToggle();
return false;
});
//итд
}
```

</code>

и подгружаете его на страницу через

```
<script src="другой-домен.рф/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
runMe();
});
</script>
```

Вот [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/67961/) делают подобное через jsonp.